# How to IntersectSet of two NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary with values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, merge, nsdictionary, intersect

Want to merge two `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary` only with `dict1` values. like `[NSMutableDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:]` and `intersectSet` (from `NSMutableSet`).

```
 Dict 1 = @{@”One”: @””, @”Two”: @”"}

 Dict 2 = @{@”One”: @”1”, @”Two”: 2, @”Three”: @”3"}
```

My expect output after merge = @{@”One”: @”1”, @”Two”: @”2"}

**UPDATE**

I am already tried with `[Dict1 addEntriesFromDictionary:Dict2]` this one give answer `@{@”One”: @”1”, @”Two”: 2, @”Three”: @”3"}`

Also I am tried with `NSMutableSet`

```
NSMutableSet *keysInA = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:tempDict.allKeys];
NSSet *keysInB = [NSSet setWithArray:tempDict1.allKeys];
[keysInA intersectSet:keysInB];
NSLog(@"keys in A that are not in B: %@", keysInA);
```

This one give output `One, Two, Three`.

So `[NSMutableSet setWithArray:]` and `[NSMutableDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:]` won't give what I expected.

If above code have anything work let clear me. Thanks.

Comment: use NSSet instate of NSDictionary

Comment: @Md.MuzahidulIslam I don't want Dict2 values. But `addEntriesFromDictionary` merge two dictvalue. I don't think that's give my answer. If I miss anything on that point out that.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Can you elaborate with code. I can't understand that. Because already I am mention in that question `NSMutableSet`.

Comment: So, you need your keys to be compared case insensitively?

Comment: @Paulw11 No, There is a mistake in question now it's update. I (For now) need only with case sensitive.

Comment: So, you want the output dictionary to contain the values from dict2 where the key also exists in dict1 ?

Comment: Yes @Paulw11, I am already mention in that question, also found a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = @{@"One": @"", @"Two": @"6"};

NSDictionary *dict2 = @{@"One": @"1", @"Two": @"2", @"Three": @"3"};

NSDictionary * dict = [dict2 dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[dict1 allKeys]];

NSLog(@"dict %@",dict);

// Log value
dict {
One = 1;
Two = 2;
}
```

Here what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
//Assuming both dictionaries have same kind of keys
NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = @{@"One" : @"", @"Two": @"", @"Three" : @""}.mutableCopy;
NSDictionary *dict2 = @{@"One" : @"1", @"Two": @"2", @"Three" : @"3",@"Four":@"4"};

for (NSString *key in dict1.allKeys)
{
    if (dict2[key])
    {
        dict1[key] = dict2[key];
    }
}
NSLog(@"Updated dict %@",dict1);
```

Comment: Thanks @raki. I thought some other way to resolve this, With default method. There is no other ways like we do for `NSArray` with `NSSet`?.

Comment: i think there is no way to do like that @user3589771

Comment: @raki You could make the code more concise by using modern dictionary access syntax using `[]`

Comment: @raki Got it. With single line. More simpler than `NSSet` union for `NSArray`